# Interactive touch display

Tags: objective-c, user-interface, user-experience

I'm looking to intercept all touch events on a parent UIView and display where the user touches but still bubble those touch events to children views i.e.. UIButtons, UITableViewCell, etc. so those children interact via their default manner.

I have no issues displaying touch events interactively on UIView using basic delegate methods:

```
    -(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
         [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    }

    -(void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
         [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    }
```

My issue at this point is bubbling these events to next responder when UIView contains other interactive children views such as UIButtons. touchesBegan: is never fired on parent view when tapping a button so I'm not able to display something "pretty" to user when taps buttons.

Is there a better way other than creating category for UIButton, UITableViewCell? Thanks

Here is an example of what I'm looking to do anytime user touches the screen... (notice the white circle when user touches buttons):
https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/154366385/disp/9532a948c71e28ffda2219600c05ffd9.gif

Comment: I would try creating a pan gesture recognizer. Set `recognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO` so it doesn't interfere with your view's touch handling.

Comment: thanks for your reply. would you attach gesture to UIButton's superview? answer is close but it seems like user would have to drag their finger to activate action: selector in parent view so if user simply tapped without moving their finger, parent UIView would never receive gesture event.

Comment: You could also use a tap gesture recognizer, or make your own. But a gesture recognizer will allow you to be notified of touches without interfering with the view's default touch handling.

Comment: attaching tap gesture to parent view doesn't seem to fire when user tap UIButton

Comment: ok so tap gesture does fire on parent view but only after user ends touch. not on touches began.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by creating a subclass of UIView.
The view should be on the top of the view hierarchy and its size should be full of the screen.

All touch events will be sent to this view. If you return NO in the pointInside:widthEvent: method, the touch event will be sent to the lower objects.

```
@implementation MyView

- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    // show bubble here
    return NO; // send touch events to lower layer objects. 
}
```

Comment: gotcha. so a subclassed overlay view. will try this and get back to you. thanks